# Can haproxy be configured to load balance requests to external / third party APIs, using round robin over multiple local interfaces?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have a server with N network interfaces, with each local address routed through a distinct external ip address. I would like to setup haproxy so that our application can make http requests using the network interfaces as a pool for round-robin. We do this because the third party API we're using has IP-based throttling, and expanding our pool of public addresses helps us make more requests (while obeying their rules.)

Is this possible? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I've got this use case right, but if you need haproxy to listen on all of your interfaces that is possible. Just bind it on every IP that you need or to bind it to all interfaces (0.0.0.0).

ie.

```
listen haproxy_frontend
   bind *:8080

   balance roundrobin

   server server1 server1.localdomain check
   server server2 server2.localdomain check
```

If the use case is to round robin requests between those local interfaces then you need to bind your application to every interface on the server and add those addresses to haproxy configuration.

ie.

```
   listen haproxy_frontend
     bind 192.168.50.81:8080

     balance roundrobin

     server local1 192.168.60.81:8081 check
     server local2 192.168.70.81:8081 check
     server local3 192.168.80.81:8081 check
```